# Google Compute Engine and Glassfish can't access from outside

Tags: google-compute-engine, glassfish-4

I created an instance (CentOS7) in GCE. I then installed Glassfish 4. However, I can't seem to access it via http/https.

```
[ank@instance-1 bin]$ sudo ./asadmin start-domain
Waiting for domain1 to start .........
Successfully started the domain : domain1
domain  Location: /opt/glassfish4/glassfish/domains/domain1
Log File: /opt/glassfish4/glassfish/domains/domain1/logs/server.log
Admin Port: 4848
Command start-domain executed successfully.
```

When trying to access http://ip_address or even http://ip_address:4848 I get "refused to connect" error.

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you'd need to open port `tcp:80`, `tcp:443` (and `tcp:4848`) on the firewall; assuming you have already assigned an external IP (or are accessing it from another internal IP on the same network, which I'd suggest for `tcp:4848`). see the documentation, concerning: [Using Firewall Rules](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-firewalls).

Comment: Thank you. That was it.